# How to list all activities exposed by an application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I think that it should be possible to get all the activities from 'third-party' application, described in the manifest file.
I can't figure out how.

for example:

```
List<Activity> aList = packManager.getActivitiesForPackage("package.name");
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do just that using the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)'s `getPackageArchiveInfo()` using the `GET_ACTIVITIES` flag. I have not tried it though

Answer (score 23):

```
public ActivityInfo[] getActivityList() throws NameNotFoundException {
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    
    ActivityInfo[] list = info.activities;

    return list;
}
```

Comment: where to use the intent i ? @easycheese

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the answer!

I think I found a solution for listing all the activities in an application too, not the most elegant though...

```
//the method gets all activities for an application
private void getAppActivities() {
    PackageManager pManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent startIntent = setStartIntent();
    List<ResolveInfo> apps = pManager.queryIntentActivities(startIntent, 0);
    int count = apps.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ResolveInfo info = apps.get(i);
        String packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setPackage(packageName);

        //activities holds the activities defined in the package
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this setStartIntent()?

Answer (score 9):

If you have the application context then use this:

```
private static void listAllActivities(Context context) {
    PackageManager pManager = context.getPackageManager();
    String packageName = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    try {
        ActivityInfo[] list = pManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;
        for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : list) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ActivityInfo = " + activityInfo.name);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```