# Calling an Application Activity from a Library Project in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-library, library-project

Ok,

So I'm making a library project of UI elements. The Library has some activities which are based of **ActionBarSherlock** which is a backwards compatibility library for the action bar in android. In these activities I would like to have a button in the action bar which will take the user home regardless of which activity they are using in the Library project.

Some terminology. The 'library' refers to the Android UI library project I'm working on. The 'Application' refers to whatever customer a developer might be using with the Library included.

Usually, when you make an activity and you want to call another, you would do something like this.

```
intent = new Intent(this, WhateverMyActivityName.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Simple enough. But here's the tricky bit. Android Libraries have little to no knowledge of what application is using them. So **'WhateverMyActivityName.class'** is useless as there is no way to predict what the developers application will call their activities.

I need to replace

```
intent = new Intent(this, WhateverMyActivityName.class);
```

with something like this

```
intent = new Intent(this, getApplication().MainActivity().getClass());
```

or possibly use some sort of intent action which will call the main Activity in the application `(Intent.ACTION_MAIN or Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)`

So in short: How do I get an applications main activity from a library project?

Comment: Just found this on the Intent documentation 

ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_HOME -- Launch the home screen.

Comment: That is a strange thing to do.. normally we create library projects so that we can reuse them for many applications.. Application independent code goes there.. Calling a particular application activity from a library project limits its usage..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Its an unusual use case but the library design has a home button and I cant think of any way to stop the library bleeding into the applciation a little. Perhaps I should have it be configurable as an XML resource so that the developer can specify which activity they want called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application calls some method in your library providing the `Intent` to be invoked, or providing the `Class` of the activity to be invoked. Your library stores that someplace and uses it.

Your assumption that the right answer is "Intent.ACTION_MAIN or Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER" may be inaccurate. For example, some apps have that be a splash screen activity (which is an issue in its own right, but that's beside the point), and that would not be where a home affordance within the app should go.

Comment: Perhaps (considering it is a library and may require some configuration) I could have the Developer define their class as an xml resource. And then call an intent to that?

Comment: @OVERTONE: I suppose that could work. Personally, I really recommend you simply let the developer supply you with the `Intent` to use, as they may wish to have some control over the flags and such.

Comment: have them supply the intent. That sounds much cleaner. I could also have them disable it if they wished. Next mission is finding a clean way to do that. Any recommendations?

Comment: @OVERTONE: As I wrote, "the application calls some method in your library providing the `Intent` to be invoked". Since we know nothing about your library, it is difficult to provide more concrete advice.

Answer (score 13):

We can use reflection to get class object.

**Class.forName("com.mypackage.myMainActivity")**

Add this code in Library project to call,

```
try {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,Class.forName("com.mypackage.myMainActivity"));
      startActivity(myIntent );
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

"com.mypackage.myMainActivity" is the Activity present in Main project, that we need to call from its Library project.

Comment: This took me days to figure out. Thanks a lot, this is the only solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of activities using the code mentioned in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210135/how-to-list-all-activities-exposed-by-an-application) post. After that loop through the resolveinfo and check the intenet filter to find the activity with your desired intent action.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand but doesn't this approach require the package name of the application? In which case, I would still need to find the package name of the developers application.

Comment: @OVERTONE: Since you have a `Context` from the developer's application (it's what you are calling `startActivity()` on), you can call `getPackageName()` on that `Context` to find the package name of the app.

Comment: You are having the context over there right, from there you can get the package manager and do rest of things.