# How to get all the activities registered in the operating system of Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In my homework I need to get all the activities that are registered to the Android operating system in a list. After that I need to filter them by having category attribute "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" and action "android.intent.action.MAIN".

I read this question ([How to list all activities exposed by an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210135/how-to-list-all-activities-exposed-by-an-application)) and about [Package Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html), but all the methods in the Package Manager only return list of the activities registered to the application package.

As I couldn't find any resource or method saying that I can get all the activities, I'm getting suspicious that I can't do that. 
Is there any way to perform this kind of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you list of packages category attribute `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` and action `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < pkgAppsList.size(); i++) {
          Log.e("Activity package", pkgAppsList.get(i).activityInfo.name);
     }
```